# Navigationbar Transparency issue

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uinavigationbar, xcode5

Initially I developed the xcode project from IOS6..now I need to make it compatible for IOS7..when I do this I got some problem with navigation bar..when I run on IOS 7 current view is overlay on navigation bar that you can see in first image.

[image]

to solve this I have added the following code

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout=UIRectEdgeNone
```

it solves my issue..but when I do this I got new issue..I lost the transparency of the navigation bar..that you can see in next image.

[image]

Comment: set the background colour of your root view controller to white?

Answer (score 3):

if your viewController has xib-file just go to the Size inspector and set in the section "iOS 6/7 Deltas" **delta-y = 44** (the height of the navigation bar) for this view. 
And be sure than in the File inspector in the field "View as:" **iOS 7.0 and later** option is selected (the default option if you use XCode 5).

**UPD**: There are also exists another way to reach success, but this is too tricky and I think the first one is better. You can add this code:

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] < 7.0) {
    CGRect rect = aView.frame;
    rect.origin.y += 44;
    aView.frame = rect;
}
```

Comment: i am using Storyboard bro...it does not work for storyboard with table view controller